# Display Image from SQL Server using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

```
protected void ddlitemname_TextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = Common.ExecuteQuery("select * from Tbl_Item_Master where Category='" + ddlitemname.SelectedItem.Text + "'");

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        txthscode.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Hscode"].ToString();
        txtselect.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["specification"].ToString();
        txttax.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Tax"].ToString();
        lblphoto.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Photo"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: by seeing your code it seems you are using a label (lblphoto) instead of image control. it should be image control img.src = ds.Table[0].Row[0]["photo"].ToString()

Comment: I try to using img1.ImageUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Photo"].ToString(); but not working. <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("~/Photo") %>'></asp:Image>

Comment: What you stored in the database in an image a URL or BLOB binary data? if you have stored Blob Field then write a handler to display image.

Comment: string filename = "";
                if (fupphoto.HasFile)
                {
                    filename = Path.GetFileName(fupphoto.PostedFile.FileName);
                    fupphoto.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Image/" + filename));

                } URL

Comment: Check the Path of the image after binding the grid. As you are using image folder while it seems in database u are saving the only filename.

Comment: http://localhost:2218/WebSite1/image/ZD.jpg | Image already in folder

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your comment and code you can use following code

```
 <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" ImageUrl =<%# string.Format("~/image/{0}",Eval("Photo"))%>
```

> 

Comment: The resource cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

protected void ddlitemname_TextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = Common.ExecuteQuery("select * from Tbl_Item_Master where Category='" + ddlitemname.SelectedItem.Text + "'");

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    txthscode.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Hscode"].ToString();
    txtselect.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["specification"].ToString();
    txttax.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Tax"].ToString();
    img1.ImageUrl = "~/Image/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Photo"].ToString();
}
```

}